# How to disable flask global installation

Tags: python, flask

I have created a python project using Flask.Let's call it projectA. I have run the command `. flask/bin/activate` to make it global. I have created another project called projectB. I ran the same command to make this Flask installation global. Next I try to install python-mysql module in the projectB. However, I noticed that it gets installed in the projectA.

How to fix this issue?

I assumed that If I can deactivate projectA global installation, this issue may be fixed. However, I didn't find a suitable command in the Flask documentation.Even though, I deleted the projectA, it still try to install the mysql module in the projectA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that I got it right: what are your `flask` folder contents?

I ask it because sometimes it is the [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) – a lot of Flask tutorials suggest installing a virtualenv under the flask folder.

If that is the case, it doesn't make the project global. On the contrary: it makes your commands use the local version of Python (the one installed inside the `flask/bin` folder), and not the global Python installed wihin your operational system.

So, your problem might not be with Flask itself, but with the lack of understanding of virtualenv.

When you run `. flask/bin/activate` inside *project A*, whatever you do in terms of Python (pip and easy_install included) will reflect only in the Python installation under project A's `flask` folder. Until you run `deactivate`. Does that make sense?

So, maybe the command you need is `deactivate` so you can jump from one virtualenv to another.

And, as a final advice, take some time to study virtualenv and, from there, go to [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org).

Comment: you are correct, I was unable to find the deactivate command. thank.